# Where do the quantum fields encode the spin information?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, spinors, klein-gordon-equation

I know basically the difference between [Klein-Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) and [Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) field is spin. But I am not sure where we need to implement this info.

The solutions of both equations are the wave packets which includes the sum of creation and annihilation operators.

$$
\Psi(x) = \int [a_pe^{-ipx} + a_p^\dagger e^{ipx}]\,d^3 p.
$$

where we use the spin information? Why should I use Klein Gordon for spin-0 and Dirac equation for 1/2?

Comment: That mode expansion does not hold for solutions of the Dirac equation. Therein the plane waves are spinors of the form $u(p)e^{ipx}$ where $u(p)$ is a 4-component spinor and encodes the information about the spin of the plane wave. The mode expansion then includes a sum over these plane waves and the usual creation and annihilation operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The momentum decomposition you wrote is valid only for a scalar (spinless), real field, satisfying the Klein-Gordon equation.

When considering a field with spin, like a [spin-$1/2$ field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields) satisfying the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), you must include the *polarization vectors*, obtaining something of the form
$$ \psi_\alpha(x) = \sum_{\textbf{p},s} N_{s,\textbf{p}}[ c_s(\textbf{p}) u_\alpha(s,\textbf{p}) e^{-ipx} + d_s^\dagger(\textbf{p}) v_\alpha(s,\textbf{p}) e^{ipx} ] $$
$$ \bar \psi_\alpha(x) = \sum_{\textbf{p},s} N_{s,\textbf{p}}[ c_s^\dagger(\textbf{p}) \bar u_\alpha(s,\textbf{p}) e^{ipx} + d_s(\textbf{p}) \bar v_\alpha(s,\textbf{p}) e^{-ipx} ] $$
where $c,c^\dagger$ and $d,d^\dagger$ are respectively annihilation/creation operators of particles and corresponding antiparticles, $u,v$ are the polarization vectors, which encode the information about the spin, and $N_{s,\textbf{p}}$ normalization factors depending on the convention used. The sum is extended over all momentum ($\textbf{p}$) and spin ($s$) eigenstates.
The objects I denoted with $ue^{-ipx}$ and $ve^{ipx}$ are called [Dirac spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor). They have *four components*, reflecting the fact that a Dirac field describes both electron and positron, each having 2 spin degrees of freedom (for a total of $2+2=4$ degrees of freedom).

In other words, ***the spin information is encoded in the additional degrees of freedom of the field***, in this case the spin-index which I denoted with $\alpha$.
This additional degrees of freedom do not evolve independently, as you can see from the (free) Dirac equation, which showing explicitly the spinor indices reads
$$ ( i \gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \partial_\mu - m \delta_{\alpha\beta})\psi_\beta(x) = 0, \quad \forall \alpha=1,2,3,4,$$
where $\gamma^\mu$ are the [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices), and a sum over the spin-index $\beta$ is implicit.

For another example you can look at spin-1 fields (e.g. [photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field)). In this case the quantum field is denoted by $A_\mu(x)$ with $\mu$ a vector index, which is the spin-index for spin-1 fields. The decomposition has now the form:
$$ A_\mu(x) = \sum_{\textbf{p},s} N_{s,\textbf{p}} [ a(s,\textbf{p}) \varepsilon_\mu(s,\textbf{p}) e^{-ipx} + a^\dagger(s,\textbf{p}) \varepsilon_\mu^*(s,\textbf{p}) e^{ipx} ]. $$
Again, $s$ denotes the spin states (which are usually called polarization states in this context), and $\varepsilon$ are the polarization vectors.

Finally, note that *each* spin component of the Dirac field satisfied the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$ (\square + m^2)\psi_\alpha(x) = 0, \forall \alpha $$
An excellent explanation of this can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95065/58382).

---

Related discussions:

- [Why would Klein-Gordon describe spin-0 scalar field while Dirac describe spin-1/2?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39542/58382)
- [Why must the Dirac equation multiplied by its complex conjugate give the KG equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95065/58382)

Comment: So for spin 1/2  α should be 1 or 2, I mean spin up and down conditions right? and 'u' will be the linear independent vector including up and down conditions? Thanks..

Comment: @Major_Tom I edited the answer to address that question. $u_\alpha(s,\textbf{p})e^{-ipx}$ is the $\alpha$ component of a Dirac spinor describing an electron with momentum $\textbf{p}$ and spin $s$. This are four-components object, despite the fact that they describe two spin degrees of freedom. Look at the wikipedia article I linked to see their explicit expressions.